# conversion varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2012

need help trying to get from the database some info and i want to call only the persons of today and i have the error the conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. TRY_CONVERT isn't a recognized function

```
select DTC.PrimerNombre+ ' ' + DTC.SegundoNombre+' '+ DTC.PrimerApellido + ' '+ DTC.SegundoApellido [Nombre], 
DGC.FechaNacimento [Fecha Nacimiento], DGC.Telefono [Teléfono Casa], DGC.Celular [Teléfono Celular]
from tblDatosTempCaptura [DTC]
LEFT JOIN  tbDatosGeneralesCiudadano as [DGC] ON DTC.IdDatosTempCaptura=DGC.IdDatosTempCaptura
where  
CONVERT (CHAR(10), datepart(day,DGC.FechaNacimento), 103) = CONVERT (CHAR(10), datepart(day,GETDATE()), 103)
```

Comment: can you show give example how your DGC.FechaNacimento look like.

Comment: Why are you even converting the data at all...?  Why not just do: `Where DatePart(Day, DGC.FechaNacimento) = DatePart(Day, GetDate())`?

Comment: FechaNacimento its just the date of birth and siyual get the same error

Comment: Let [TRY_CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) be your friend. Select that and the original value, see where the TRY_CONVERT returns NULL and voila, you got the culprit. Note: this comment is for SQL Server databases. I guess other RDBMS's have similar functionality?

Comment: so this happen 'TRY_CONVERT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: What DBMS are you using, and what version? It is important to tag your question what the specific tag for the DBMS and its version. Each DBMS has its own flavor of SQL, and different versions have different functions that are supported.

Comment: SQL Server 2012 v 11

Comment: As you can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993(v=sql.110).aspx), TRY_CONVERT is supported in SQL Server 2012. Absolutely sure you have version 2012? What is the result of `select @@version as 'sql server version'` when you run it on the database you are executing on?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3156.0 (X64) 
 May  4 2015 18:48:09 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Web Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the query where you say TRY_CONVERT isn't a recognized function?

Comment: Also, you do realize that `datepart(day,DGC.FechaNacimento)` is returning a number, not a date, right? That number being the day of `DGC.FechaNacimento`. Is the type of `FechaNacimento` DATE or DATETIME?

Comment: have it on datetime

Comment: Instead of `where  
CONVERT (CHAR(10), datepart(day,DGC.FechaNacimento), 103) = CONVERT (CHAR(10), datepart(day,GETDATE()), 103)`, try with `WHERE datepart(day,DGC.FechaNacimento)=datepart(day,GETDATE())`.

Comment: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. TT. this error shows

Comment: could you tell us what do you get when you only try to select datepart(day, DGC.FechaNacimento)?

Comment: Cannot find either column "DGC" or the user-defined function or aggregate "DGC.FechaNacimento", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: SET DATEFORMAT ymd
SELECT DTC.PrimerNombre+' '+DTC.SegundoNombre+' '+DTC.PrimerApellido+' '+DTC.SegundoApellido [Nombre],
       DGC.FechaNacimento [Fecha Nacimiento],
       DGC.Telefono [Teléfono Casa],
       DGC.Celular [Teléfono Celular]
FROM tblDatosTempCaptura [DTC]
     LEFT JOIN tbDatosGeneralesCiudadano AS [DGC] ON DTC.IdDatosTempCaptura = DGC.IdDatosTempCaptura
WHERE convert  (date(10), MONTH(day,DGC.FechaNacimento), 102)  = convert (date(10), DAY(day,GETDATE()), 102)                 and now this errorThe month function requires 1 argument(s).

Comment: Sameeh, if you get that error after trying what I suggested, that would mean that the column `FechaNacimento` in table `tbDatosGeneralesCiudadano` is of type VARCHAR, not DATETIME as you claimed earlier. Before I'm willing to continue with helping you, please edit your question and add the table definition of `tbDatosGeneralesCiudadano` to your question (right click the table in SSMS, and script the CREATE statement, then copy/paste it in your question and use the `{}` button to format it properly).

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2012 and you get an error when you invoke the `TRY_CONVERT` function, it means that you are using an older compatibility level. If you want to change your database to use to the SQL Server 2012 compatibility level, execute `ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL=110`

Comment: okay guys thanks very much just solve it :D